# Is there a way to differentiate a functional (a function where the input itself is a function and the output is a real number)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, vectors

---

Edit I've had a think and here's where I am:

**Suppose $A$ and $B$ are complete metric spaces**, for example
$$A = [-1, 1]^n, \ \ B = \mathbb{R}^m$$
where the metric is something like the Euclidean distance or the Manhattan distance - any metric that makes these spaces complete metric spaces will do.

Then define the **set of bounded, continuous, functions from $A \rightarrow B$** as
$$\Theta_A^B =  \{ \theta : A \rightarrow B, \ \text{ s.t. } \theta \text{ is bounded and continous} \}$$

Note that by *bounded*, I mean that $d_B(\theta(a),\ b) \in \mathbb{R}$ is finite for all $a \in A$, where $b$ is some constant in $B$ (e.g. we can assume $b$ is the zero vector $b = \mathbf{0}$).

By *continuous*, I mean the following:
$$ \text{Let } \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots\} \text{ be a cauchy sequence in } A \text{ converging to } a, \text{ then } \{\theta(a_1), \theta(a_2), \theta(a_3), \dots\} \text{ converges to } \theta(a)$$

The above means that we can treat $\Theta_A^B$ as a complete metric space with the distance function defined as
$$d_{\Theta}(f,g) = \text{Sup}\{ \ d_B(f(a),\ g(a)) \ : a \in A \}$$
in other words, the distance between $f$ and $g$ is the maximal gap between them at a point.

Now, it is a theorem that $(\Theta_A^B, d_{\Theta})$ it itself a complete metric space, where the points are not finite-dimensional vectors (as is the case for $A$ and $B$) but rather infinite-dimensional functions (limited to bounded, continous, functions from $A$ to $B$).

We are getting close to a proposed definition of differentiation --- **comments welcome on it**.

$$\text{Let } u : \Theta_A^B \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ be a bounded, continous, function}$$

Then we define a derivative of $u$ with respect to some element $f \in \Theta_A^B$ as
$$u\prime_f(\theta) = \text{Lim}_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \left\{ \frac{u(\theta + \delta f) - u(\theta)}{\delta} \right\} $$

Here, $\delta$ is simply a small real number from $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.
(Note that I have snuck in an assumption that **$B$ is an abelian group** $(B, +)$ where the inverse of $+$ is of course $-$.)

Since $f$ is bounded, I believe this definition is well-defined. If the derivative does not depend on the chosen $f \in \Theta$, i.e. the derivative of $u$ is the same for any such choice, then this is the derivative by definition. **Does this definition $u\prime(\theta)$ function work?**

---

---

***Old question - see simplified updated above.***

I will need to inevitably revise the language of this question after comments telling me my notation and terminology are wrong, but I'll do my best to ask.

I want to optimise a real-time strategy over a time interval $(0, \lambda)$.

To precisely define a *strategy* $\kappa$ as a function

$$\kappa : (0, \lambda) \overset{\mathrm{\Delta}}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{A}$$

where $\mathbb{A}$ is an *action*, e.g. direction and magnitude of steering a car wheel and magnitude of acceleration. In my question, $\mathbb{A}$ is a set such as $I_1 \times I_2 \dots I_n$ whereby each $I_i$ is a real interval (such as $(0,1)$ or $\mathbb{R}$).

It might be possible to generalise such that the set of *actions* $\mathbb{A}$ is any dense metric space, but I am unsure about this.

The notation above $(\overset{\mathrm{\Delta}}{\rightarrow})$ is meant to state that **$\kappa$ is a continuously-differentiable function over its domain**, so that the gradient function
$$\kappa \prime : (0, \lambda) \rightarrow \mathbb{A} $$

is well-defined and continuous over its domain.

In the above, $\lambda > 0$ is called the "lookahead parameter", as it will define the time in which the strategy is planned. I'll assume $\lambda$ is fixed (e.g. to $1.0$ or $\sqrt{2}$).

Now, each strategy $\kappa$ has an expected outcome score $\Psi(\kappa) \in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, each strategy outputs some score:
$$\Psi : \left( (0, \lambda) \overset{\mathrm{\Delta}}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{A} \right) \overset{\mathrm{\Delta}}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R} $$

where again $\Psi$ itself is continuously-differentiable...

The question (that you've already asked yourself I expect!!) is what it even means for $\Psi$ to be continuously-differentiable. **That's the main thrust of my question - can we GIVE it some reasonable meaning.**

The first step is making sense of a "$\delta$ change".
For calculus in $\mathbb{R}$, $\delta$ is simply an arbitrarily small number (sometimes called $\epsilon$, although it's important that $\delta$ may be small-positive and small-negative).
For calculus in $\mathbb{C}$, a "$\delta$ change" can be defined naturally as a pair of arbitrarily small changes $\delta = \delta_{Real} + i \times \delta_{Img}$, where both $\delta_{Real}$ and $\delta_{Img}$ are arbitrarily small real numbers (not necessarily the same or even related).

For a vector space (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}^n$, a "$\delta$ change" can be defined naturally as $\delta = (\delta_1, \delta_2, \dots, \delta_n)$ where again each $\delta_i$ is an arbitrarily small real number (both positive or negative). If we were doing calculus with inputs in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we would consider the following:
$$\text{As } v \rightarrow v + \delta,\ \ f(v) \rightarrow f(v + \delta)$$

Indeed if we assume that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ then the definition of its derivative is the vector
$$ \left( \frac{f(v + \delta) - f(v)}{\delta_1}, \frac{f(v + \delta) - f(v)}{\delta_2}, \dots , \frac{f(v + \delta) - f(v)}{\delta_n} \right)$$
assuming that such a vector is unique and well-defined.

As always, I might be wrong about the above... please correct me (nicely...) if I'm wrong.

Is there a way to continue generalising the concept of differentiability all the way up to $\Psi$, where the input is not a vector but a continuously-differentiable-function?

My intuition is that a continuous function $\kappa$ is very similar to an infinitely-long vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, where the $i^{\text{th}}$ index in $v$ maps to a real-number $v[i]$, so too $\kappa(i)$ maps to a real number (for $i$ in the domain of $\kappa$).

Comment: You should look up differentiable manifolds and related concepts.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look in more detail now but a quick glance makes me realise what I terrible can of worms I may have opened for myself! I didn't expect this to be so hard (I'm programming the rational behaviour of enemy AI in a game like a racing game or a dogfighting game).

Comment: Without the numerator depending on $\delta$, your limit expression for $u'_f(\theta)$ won't exist. Maybe think about some examples of functionals: Would you expect the functionals $f \mapsto f(a)$ or $f \mapsto \int_A |f(x)|^2\, dx$ or $f \mapsto \int_A  f(x) g(x)\, dx$ to be differentiable? What would those derivatives be?

Comment: Have you looked at any standard texts on *calculus of variations*? This is precisely the environment it deals with.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll read up more on Calculus of Variations and have a think about the numerator! I've never heard of this topic and didn't study functionals in university so this is pushing me far!

Comment: @aschepler - there was a typo before - I meant to write $\delta f$ rather than just $f$. Silly me